Convert a Json with Avro Schema in Nifi
I have a json with this:
{
  "infoPedido" : [ {
    "VBELN" : "5479223891",
    "POSNR" : "000140",
    "LFIMG" : "1.0"
  }, {
    "VBELN" : "5479223891",
    "POSNR" : "000040",
    "LFIMG" : "5.0"
  }, {
    "VBELN" : "53331",
    "POSNR" : "000090",
    "LFIMG" : "5.0"
  }
]

I need to convert this in avro schema to XML in:
<E1EDL20>
                <VBELN>5479223891</VBELN>
                <E1EDL24>
                    <POSNR>000140</POSNR>
                    <LFIMG>1.0</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                </E1EDL24>
                <E1EDL24>
                    <POSNR>000040</POSNR>
                    <LFIMG>1.0</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                </E1EDL24>
</E1EDL20>
<E1EDL20>
                <VBELN>53331</VBELN>
                <E1EDL24>
                    <POSNR>000090</POSNR>
                    <LFIMG>5.0</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                </E1EDL24>
</E1EDL20>

The value VRKME is fixed (CS).
I need to convert in this form because I'm gonna separate with de VBELN value.
